# How can you calculate the exact position of the Earth taking into account the gravitational attraction of Mars and the Sun?

Tags: gravity, planets, solar-system

I think there must be a formula to calculate the exact position of the Earth taking into account the gravitational attraction of Mars and the Sun. Is it possible with vectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering the just Sun, Earth, and Mars, this would be a [three-body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem).  An exact solution for a three-body problem might be interesting mathematically, but if by exact position you mean the *real* position then you'll need to take into account much more than just Mars.  Numerical integration techniques are standard for [n-body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem) problems such as the Solar System.

Comment: A solution ignoring the Moon would be way off.  And I'm sure Jupiter exerts more gravitational influence on Earth than Mars does.  You could mathematically determine the position of Earth in a Sun-Earth-Mars system (though not in a closed-form equation), but it wouldn't match reality.